# CSS or probably a Jquery solution for Menu

Tags: css

I have a menu, which is responsive, the only problem it has is with the sub-level, please check the example here

http://jsfiddle.net/6vp3U/409/

```
 .sf-menu ul {
    position:static !important;
    display: none !important;
 }
 .xpopdrop ul {
    display: block !important;
 }
```

in above example, under "Item 2" there is another sub-menu under "item 2.1", that doesn't work according to the media query, I want this to work as other sub menus working, please drag the fiddle center area to see this in action.. I know it has something to do with the css "ul".. tried a lot, couldn't find a solution, I would appreciate if someone experienced with CSS can spend 5 minutes and help me fix this..

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add two selectors:

```
.xpopdrop ul ul {
    display: none!important;
 }
.xpopdrop .xpopdrop ul {
    display: block!important;
 }
```

It seems like worked...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vp3U/410/)